# Email validation. Regular expression allows more than 1 "@" sign for some reason

Tags: regex, kotlin

I'm trying to validate e-mail. Everything works fine, but the regular expression does not forbid more than one at-sign (@) for some reason.

I'm using Kotlin for the regular expressions.

My Regex:

```
^((?=.*\\d)(?!.*[+$=()*?&:;^%#!\\[\\]{}<>,/|`~'№])(?=[a-zA-Z]).{4,})([@])([a-zA-Z]{2,})(\\.[a-zA-Z]{2})$
```

The address must look like this: `johndoe1@yahoo.en`:

- At least one digit, and at least 4 letters before the "@ " character
- Then one `@` character.
- Then an arbitrary number of letters (at least 2).
- Then a dot.
- Then only 2 letters of the domain.

I think this part

```
(?=[a-zA-Z]).{4,}) ([@])
```

is causing a problem, but i don't know why. Maybe you can help me?

Comment: Can you give us some expected inputs and expected outputs, so we can see your scope ?

Comment: @totok I have an editText field. I enter my email address there. The address must look like this: "johndoe1@yahoo.en". At least one digit, and at least 4 letters before the "@ " character. Then one "@ " character. Then an arbitrary number of letters (at least 2). Then a dot. Then only 2 letters of the domain.

Comment: @totok Everything works fine, but for some reason regex allows more than one "at-sign" (@) character.

Comment: Use ``Regex("""^(?=.*\d)(?!.*[+$=()*?&:;^%#!\[\]{}<>,\/|`~'№])(?=[a-zA-Z])[^@]{4,}@[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2}$""")``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, finally it works as it should be! But i don't get it, [a-zA-Z] contains "@" sign or what? I thought it contains only letters. I hope you can explain why it works this way.

Comment: There was a problem in another part of the regex. BTW, I suggest using raw string literals to avoid backslash related problems. Also, you probably used the `Pattern.COMMENTS` option, but did not include it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that `.` matches any char but line break chars. You need to restrict it to match any char but `@` char.

`[A-Za-z]` pattern is not matching the user part, you only use it to make sure the username part starts with a letter, and that the domain and TLD only consist of letters.

That means, your fixed regex will look like

```
val regex = Regex("""^(?=.*\d)(?!.*[+$=()*?&:;^%#!\[\]{}<>,\/|`~'№])(?=[a-zA-Z])[^@]{4,}@[a-zA-Z]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2}$""")
```

but it does not guarantee that you will match all emails. Hopefully, it does what you need.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qxlDrq/1).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*\d)` -  there must be at least one digit in the string
- `(?!.*[+$=()*?&:;^%#!\[\]{}<>,\/|`~'№])` - there must be at least one special char from the set defined in the char class
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])` - the username part must start with a letter
- `[^@]{4,}` - the username part must contain 4 or more chars other than `@`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,}` - two or more letters
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` - two letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple version of an email regex from Jan Goyvaerts: `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`

Here is the RFC 5322 Official Standard regex for verifying email addresses:


`` (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]) ``

I think you'd be best off using those.